# differents between a closed operator and an operator s.t. $T(F)$ is closed for all closed set $F$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(T,\mathcal D(T))$ an operator. For me, the definition of a closed function $f:X\to Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces) is a function s.t. $f(F)$ is closed in $Y$ for all closed set in $X$.

Here, we say that $(T,\mathcal D(T))$ (where $T:\mathcal D(T)\subset X\to Y$) is closed if the graph $G(T)=\{(x,T(x))\mid x\in \mathcal D(T)\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$. Since the two definitions are different, is there a linear operator s.t. $G(T)$ is closed but there is a closed set $F$ of $\mathcal D(T)$ s.t. $T(F)$ is not closed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a linear space $X$, with two different compatible topologies such that one is strictly weaker than the other. For example the weak and weak-* topology on a dual infinite dimensional space.
The identity map is continuous, so the graph is closed, on the other hand if the identity map is a closed map the topologies coincide.

Comment: Nice answer. :)